# Bitcoin Transaction was sent to me with low fee and I used unconfirmed funds?

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I was sent 0.29 btc to my wallet lastnight (bitpay) but it said the sender used low fees so it could take very long or be dropped? I'm not familiar. But I needed these funds in coinbase so I transferred some there and the rest topped off my bitpay visa card. I really need access to these funds, please help what can be done? Thank you.

The bitcoin address is.

18V9wQDAesH64XTDN6UJYw7DDzs8e92LtW

Comment: That is an address not a transaction.

Comment: 18V9wQDAesH64XTDN6UJYw7DDzs8e92LtW     ....yes it's the address it was sent to, it currently shows it unconfirmed on blockchain and also blockcypher?

Comment: I don't see a 3 BTC transaction for that address. Do you have the txid?

Comment: Yes I just found the TXID number please help me someone.    fa9cd3945061cd715c56ff51e58cb941ec9897cc4e6dbaf5484315dd4f5e1fad

Comment: The fees were 18$. That's not very low. So it could be confirmed within a few days.

Comment: that's nuts, its never taken me longer than a few hours from this same sender. Now if I sent the money to coinbase and one other place before the money was confirmed, what happens now? Am I at risk of losing any money here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still no confirmations. What am I to expect here? Can someone help?